# PHP open .txt file with full URL

Tags: php

I want to be able to read the contents of a file from its full domain and filepath, so something like:

`http://www.example.com/files/file.txt`

What I can't do in this instance is:

`../files/file.txt`

I have tried curl, fopen, file_get_contents and would rather use curl but cannot get it to work for any of them.

Is there an obvious reason why this isn't working that I am missing?

Here are the code snippets for each attempt, parhaps someone knows what's wrong with one of them?

Incidentally, if I could do `../files/file.txt` it works for each option.

```
$file = "http://www.example.com/files/file.txt";
```

fopen:

```
$f=fopen($file,'r'); 
$data=''; 
while(!feof($f)) 
    $data.=fread($f,$size); 
fclose($f);
```

curl:

```
function curl($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

$data = curl($file);
```

file_get_contents:

```
$data = file_get_contents($file);
```

Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: Shared hosting? Remote connections could be disabled by the host

Comment: Do you see any errors in your server's error log? It could be a permission issue.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to your script and check your error log. but if none work @Farkie is most likely right.

Comment: Try changing the domain. From example.com to localhost.

Comment: Is the file you are trying to read on the same server as the script or a different server?

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` disabled in your PHP configuration?

Comment: allow_url_fopen is ON in config. allow_url_include is Off

Comment: The file I'm trying to access is on the same server as the script @Crontab

Comment: If that's the case, don't try to include using a URL.  Use the absolute or relative path name to access the file.

Answer (score 3):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) works fine for URLs with PHP 4 >= 4.3.0 and PHP 5:

"A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled"

Many shared hosters have this option disabled, or are using an older version of PHP and are  blocking loading external files using PHP's [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php).

Start with [enabling error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php) and have a look at your hosters web site to see if he's blocking external files.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps url fopen are disabled on your hosting and urls from another domains are just disabled?

**php.ini** *var* **allow_url_fopen**  must be **on**